# In J2EE Strutrs 2 Hibernate project, Unable to get a ORM object of Pojo Class with a foreign Key? is it possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, foreign-keys, pojo

```
     Session s=HibernateUtil.getSession();

    TicketDetails td=(TicketDetails)s.get(TicketDetails.class,ticketId);
```

TicketDetail is a object of a POJO class, and its working fine with a primary key.*

```
    ClientDetails cd=(ClientDetails)s.get(ClientDetails.class,
 td.getLoginDetails().getLoginId());
```

ClientDetail is also a object of POJO Class, and am getting error msg with the foreign key here which is td.getLoginDetails().getLoginId()*

How do I get ClientDetail object with this foreign key?

The general structure of the ClientDetail POJO class is:

```
public class ClientDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer clientId;
    private LoginDetails loginDetails;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String passwd;
    private String address;
    private String city;
```

---

My problem is associated with foreign key only..

1. [ticket_details] database has the Client's [loginId] and which i have because i have ticket_details's Primary Key ie [TicketId],
2. Client has one [LoginID] as well as a [ClientId], and
3. Where as [Client_Detail] database has client's [loginId] as foreign key and [ClientId] is its Primary key.
4. So what i need to do is With the help of [Ticket_Detail] database i have client's [login ID] and with it i need to get the client's [ClientId] and from [Client_details] database via Client's [LoginId] which is a foreign Key for it. (and obviously at this point i dont have [client_details's primary key] ).

if i cant do it then whats the purpose of creating Foreign key in database???

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that you need a primary key of `ClientDetail`.

So you can do

```
ClientDetails cd=(ClientDetails)s.get(ClientDetails.class, clientId);
```

You can also do if `LoginDetails` primary key is `id`, then you can get other keys after load.

```
LoginDetails loginDetails =(LoginDetails)s.get(LoginDetails.class, td.getLoginDetails().getId()); 
ClientDetails cd=(ClientDetails)s.get(ClientDetails.class, loginDetails.getLoginId());
```

Foreign keys are lazy by default, but you could change that if needed by forcing to fetch associated entities. For this purpose you should configure fetch attribute to `FetchType.EAGER`.

Comment: kk now i have added the additional info..  srry fr that..
but plz help me now .. in case u can?